# Ping host to determine host name

Tags: c#

Hi i am new to programing and cant see what is wrong with this code
i have a textbox that i will add a host name to and then the S1 string will be add and then pinged all i want the code to do is to list what is the correct host name so if i enter the name Computer in the text box it will ping the following

```
ComputerDT
ComputerLT
computerTB
computerR0
```

only one will have the correct host name and i want to list it in list box one its all working fine apart from the last if statement

```
if (host1 != "")
    listBox1.Items.Add(host1);
```

and i get host1 not in local context i cant see why this is wrong

can anyone help please

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string S1 = "DT";
        public string S2 = "LT";
        public string S3 = "R0";
        public string S4 = "TB";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        update();
    }



    static string Ping(string host)
    {
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
        string errMessage = string.Empty;
        string returnMessage;


        // Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
        // but change the fragmentation behavior.
        options.DontFragment = true;

        // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        int timeout = 120;
        try
        {
            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(host, timeout, buffer, options);

            if (!(reply == null))
            {
                switch (reply.Status)
                {
                    case IPStatus.Success:
                        returnMessage = string.Format("Reply from {0}: bytes={1} time={2}ms TTL={3}", reply.Address, reply.Buffer.Length, reply.RoundtripTime, reply.Options.Ttl);
                        break;
                    case IPStatus.TimedOut:
                        returnMessage = "Connection has timed out...";
                        break;
                    default:
                        returnMessage = string.Format("Ping failed: {0}", reply.Status.ToString());
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
                returnMessage = "Connection failed for an unknown reason...";
        }
        catch (PingException ex)
        {
            returnMessage = string.Format("");
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            returnMessage = string.Format("");
        }


        return returnMessage;






    }



    public void update()
    {


        string[] lines = textBox1.Lines;
        List<string> myCollection = new List<string>();

        string host1;


        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains(""))

                myCollection.Add(line + S1);
            myCollection.Add(line + S2);
            myCollection.Add(line + S3);
            myCollection.Add(line + S4);
        }

        myCollection.ToArray();



        {
            foreach (string val in myCollection)

                host1 = Ping(val);

            if (host1 != "")

                listBox1.Items.Add(host1);


        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

avoid using the following constructs

```
if(condition)
    expression;

foreach(condition)
    expression;
```

instead always use braces - you will then spot the problem

Comment: The OP looks like a Python programmer (or similar). - **C# doesn't care about whitespace! It's all about the `{` `}`!**

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `foreach` loop in braces:

```
foreach (string val in myCollection)
{
    host1 = Ping(val);
    if (host1 != "")
        listBox1.Items.Add(host1);
}
```

otherwise is will only loop the first line. (which is why `host1` is no longer in scope)

the if statement above it looks iffy {chuckle} as well:

```
if (line.Contains(""))

    myCollection.Add(line + S1);
myCollection.Add(line + S2);
myCollection.Add(line + S3);
myCollection.Add(line + S4);
```

should be

```
if (line.Contains(""))  // this will always be true.  Need to use a proper check here
{
    myCollection.Add(line + S1);
    myCollection.Add(line + S2);
    myCollection.Add(line + S3);
    myCollection.Add(line + S4);
}
```

Comment: While the braces are a good idea, it doesn't actually solve the problem, because host1 is being declared outside of the scope of the foreach block?

Comment: Yes it will because `host1` is not _initialized_ outside of the `foreach` loop